# Object of class PrestaShopWebservice could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, webservice, foreach, prestashop

Estoy consumiendo un webservice de una tienda de prestashop 1.7 en donde estoy extrayendo algunos datos, el tema aca es que estoy obteniendo un error en algunos casos y por una parte no entiendo bien el error, motivo por el cual no se bien como solucionarlo, el error es el siguiente:

```
[2022-10-26 19:32:01] local.ERROR: Object of class PrestaShopWebservice could not be converted to string {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Object of class PrestaShopWebservice could not be converted to string at D:\\WebApps\\sistema\\app\\Jobs\\syncCustomerDniPrestashop.php:61)
[stacktrace]
```

Tengo un job programado en Laravel como lo muestro en el siguiente codigo, para este caso tengo todos los id de los clientes, correspondiente a las de 76 mil registros, estos los paso por un foreach y los recorro, por cada id voy a un endpoint que contiene informacion de un cliente y traigo esa informacion, de momento de los 76 mil registros, solo he logrado obtener alrededor de 17 mil registros con la informacion completa, sin embargo en algun momento me arroja el error ya mencionado, `Object of class PrestaShopWebservice could not be converted to string`

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\ApiLog;
use App\Models\Customer;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use PrestaShopWebservice;
use PrestaShopWebserviceException;

class syncCustomerDniPrestashop implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        $customerNumber = Customer::select('id', 'prestashop_id')
                                    ->orderBy('prestashop_id', 'ASC')
                                    ->get();

        foreach($customerNumber as $number) {
            try {
                $webService = new PrestaShopWebservice('https://mywebsite.cl/', 'apikey', false);
                // call to retrieve all customers
                $xml = $webService->get([
                    'resource' => 'addresses',
                    'filter[id_customer]' => $number->prestashop_id, // Here we use hard coded value but of course you could get this ID from a request parameter or anywhere else
                ]);                
                $resources = $xml->addresses->children();
                    foreach($resources as $resource) {                       
                        $attributes = $resource->attributes();
                        $resourceId = $attributes['id'];
                        //dd($resourceId);
                        $neworder = Customer::updateOrCreate(
                            ['prestashop_id' => $number->prestashop_id],
                            ['id_address_prestashop' => $resourceId]
                        );
                    }
            } catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $ex) {
                // Shows a message related to the error
                echo 'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage();
                $neworder = ApiLog::Create(
                    [
                        'idendpoint' => $number->prestashop_id,
                        'endpoint' => 'Obteniendo direcciones completas, syncCustomerFromPrestashop',
                        'errordetails' => $ex->getMessage(),
                        'fechaerror' => now(),            
                    ]
                );
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Frente a esto no se bien como obtener mas informacion al respecto o bien si hay alguna forma que pueda utilizar para resolver, una alternativa que estaba probando es hacer un casts en el modelo de Laravel,

```
    protected $casts = [
        'telephone' => 'string',
        'telephone_2' => 'string',
        'email' => 'string',
        'name' => 'string',
        'id_address_prestashop' => 'string',
        'dni' => 'string'
    ];
```

Alguna idea o algo que pueda corregir o agregar en mi codigo?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea 61 de syncCustomerDniPrestashop? Será donde estás concatenando un string `'Other error: <br />' . $ex->getMessage()`?

Comment: Si tienes razon, mas bien era el otro echo que habia puesto mas abajo, donde mi idea era ir mostrando en la consola en que registro iba navegando, por ejemplo a cada url que va con el id que tiene dentro del foreach, lo quite y desaparecio el error, pero igual sabes como se podra hacer eso? mas que nada para efectos de monitoreo del jobs... pór ejemplo va a la url https://mywebsite.cl/1 luego imprimir https://mywebsite.cl/2, y asi https://mywebsite.cl/3

Comment: Para verlo en directo en la consola que ejecutás `queue:work`? No sé si sea posible, pero podes guardarlo en un archivo con Log::debug y hacer un `tail -f` del archivo en una consola

Comment: a si, si voy guardando en un log los errores que pueda ir encontrando, y para ejecutarlo los corres con ```php artisan schedule:work``` esto en Laravel

Comment: Claro, a lo que iba es que podrías verlo en directo en otra consola con tail, porque entendí que querias hacer eso. Si no, abris el archivo con el IDE y lo ves ahí